# Gradient Descent in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am taking machine learning class in courseera. The machine learning is a pretty area for me. In first programming exercise I am having some difficulties in gradient decent algorithm. If anyone can help me I will be appreciate.

Here is the instructions for updating thetas;

"You will implement gradient descent in the file gradientDescent.m. The loop structure has been written for you, and you only need to supply the updates to θ within each iteration.

```
    function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
    %GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
    %   theta = GRADIENTDESENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
    %   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

   % Initialize some useful values
   m = length(y); % number of training examples
   J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

   for iter = 1:num_iters

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Perform a single gradient step on the parameter vector
%               theta. 
%
% Hint: While debugging, it can be useful to print out the values
%       of the cost function (computeCost) and gradient here.
%
    % ============================================================

% Save the cost J in every iteration    
J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

So here is what I did to update thetas simultaneously;

```
    temp0 = theta(1,1) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y));
    temp1 = theta(2,1) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y).*X);
    theta(1,1) = temp0;
    theta(2,1) = temp1;
```

I am getting error when I run this code. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What error are you getting? Matlab's error messages are usually quite helpful.

Comment: here is the error that I got; 
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in gradientDescent (line 20)
    temp1 = theta(2,1) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y).*X);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that you got `Error using .* Matrix dimensions must agree. Error in gradientDescent (line 20) temp1 = theta(2,1) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y).*X);` means that the `.*` is not working. So, before that line, add in the following code:

```
size(X*theta-y)
size(X)
```

If you want to do `(X*theta-y).*X`, then both `X*theta-y` and `X` should be the same size. If they aren't, you will need to check your algorithm.

Comment: I understood the point. After some research i found someone used the code below 
    theta = theta - (alpha/m *  (X * theta-y)' * X)';
as result of this code, answer is [-3.6303 1.1664]. However, it seems not correct, because J value is not decreasing in each steps. Also, theta still seems [0,0] which is initial values of thetas . Do you have any idea how should I type the code to update theta simultaneously.

Comment: @Ram I did this course some time ago and I totally think the problem is the * multiplication. try your same code using the .*

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works now. Now, I need to understand what exactly meaning of vectorization, so i will open another title. Anyways, thank you again.

Answer (score 20):

I have explained **why** you can use the vectorized form:

`theta = theta - (alpha/m) * (X' * (X * theta - y));` or the equivalent

`theta = theta - (alpha/m) * ((X * theta - y)' * X)';`

in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42330833/842837).

### Quoting it below:

---

Explanation for the matrix version of gradient descent algorithm:

This is the gradient descent algorithm to fine tune the value of θ:
[image]

Assume that the following values of X, y and θ are given:

- m = number of training examples
- n = number of features + 1

[image]

Here

- m = 5 (training examples)
- n = 4 (features+1)
- X = m x n matrix
- y = m x 1 vector matrix
- θ = n x 1 vector matrix
- x<sup>i</sup> is the i<sup>th</sup> training example
- x<sub>j</sub> is the j<sup>th</sup> feature in a given training example

Further,

- `h(x) = ([X] * [θ])` (m x 1 matrix of predicted values for our training set)
- `h(x)-y = ([X] * [θ] - [y])` (m x 1 matrix of Errors in our predictions)

*whole objective of machine learning is to minimize Errors in predictions.* Based on the above corollary, our Errors matrix is `m x 1` vector matrix as follows:

[image]

**To calculate new value of θ<sub>j</sub>, we have to get a summation of all errors (m rows) multiplied by j<sup>th</sup> feature value of the training set X.** That is, take all the values in E, individually multiply them with j<sup>th</sup> feature of the **corresponding** training example, and add them all together. This will help us in getting the new (and hopefully better) value of θ<sub>j</sub>. Repeat this process for all j or the number of features. In matrix form, this can be written as:

[image]

This can be simplified as:
[image]

- `[E]' x [X]` will give us a row vector matrix, since E' is 1 x m matrix and X is m x n matrix. But we are interested in getting a column matrix, hence we transpose the resultant matrix.

More succinctly, it can be written as:
[image]

The same result can also be written as:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
theta = theta - (alpha/m) * (X' * (X * theta - y));
```

this is the right answer

Answer (score 4):

```
temp0 = theta(1,1) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y));
temp1 = theta(2,1) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y).*X(:,2));
theta(1,1) = temp0;
theta(2,1) = temp1;
```

Or you can use the code below. It's simpler. There are only two parameters theta1 and theta2. But if more parameters exist, it's much better.

```
for i=1:2
    theta(i) = theta(i) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y).*X(:,i));
end
```

Comment: I think the second option does not work since you are not updating simultaneously all values of theta

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing to note in this question:

```
X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1)];
```

so

```
theta = theta - (alpha / m) * (X' * (X * theta - y));
```

and

```
temp0 = theta(1, 1) - (alpha / m) * sum((X * theta - y));
temp1 = theta(2, 1) - (alpha / m) * sum((X * theta - y) .* X(:, 2));
theta(1, 1) = temp0;
theta(2, 1) = temp1;
```

both are right