# Gradient descent not updating theta values

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

Using the vectorized version of gradient as described at : 
[gradient descent seems to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479353/gradient-descent-seems-to-fail)

```
theta = theta - (alpha/m *  (X * theta-y)' * X)';
```

The theta values are not being updated, so whatever initial theta value
this is the values that is set after running gradient descent :

example1 :

```
m = 1
X = [1]
y = [0]
theta = 2
theta = theta - (alpha/m .* (X .* theta-y)' * X)'

theta =

    2.0000
```

example2 :

```
m = 1
X = [1;1;1]
y = [1;0;1]
theta = [1;2;3]
theta = theta - (alpha/m .* (X .* theta-y)' * X)'

theta =

    1.0000
    2.0000
    3.0000
```

Is `theta = theta - (alpha/m *  (X * theta-y)' * X)';` a correct vectorised implementation of gradient descent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theta = theta - (alpha/m *  (X * theta-y)' * X)';` is indeed the correct vectorized implementation of gradient-descent.

You totally forgot to set the learning rate, `alpha`.

After setting `alpha = 0.01`, your code becomes:

```
m = 1                # number of training examples
X = [1;1;1]
y = [1;0;1]
theta = [1;2;3]
alpha = 0.01
theta = theta - (alpha/m .* (X .* theta-y)' * X)'
theta =

   0.96000
   1.96000
   2.96000
```